# print date like 'Y-m-d H:i:s"in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a built in way in javascript that formats a date object in a format like “Y-m-d H:i:s”?

I use

```
var since= new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified"));
alert("modified:: " +since.getDate()+'.'+(since.getMonth()+1)+'. '+ since.getHours()+':'+since.getMinutes())
```

But that cuts off all leading zeros

Comment: Create a simple function that pad zeros if needed, if that's your concern. There's no built-in way to get the exact format you want. But you could use `since.toISOString()`, which gets you close. Of if you don't like either of those suggestions, moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) has great support for date parsing and printing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function:

```
function pad(number) {
  if ( number < 10 ) {
    return '0' + number;
  }
  return number;
}

pad(since.getDate())+'.'+pad(since.getMonth()+1)+'. '+ pad(since.getHours())+':'+pad(since.getMinutes())
```

For Y-m-d H:i:s format use following example:

```
pad(since.getFullYear()) + '-' + pad(since.getMonth()+1) + '-' + pad(since.getDate()) + ' ' + pad(since.getHours()) + ':' + pad(since.getMinutes()) + ':' + pad(since.getSeconds())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
function LeadingZero(s,max) {
    var z = max-s.length+1;
    z = z>1 ? Array(z).join('0') : '';
    return (z + s);     
}

alert("modified:: " +LeadingZero(since.getDate(),2)+'.'+LeadingZero(since.getMonth()+1,2)+'. '+ LeadingZero(since.getHours(),2));
```

But I recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), a library for handling dates in JS. It has built in a formatter and can do a lot of other stuff.

In moment you can do it this way:

```
var d = moment(since);
alert(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```